# c# change form strings on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

My code which changes caption of navigation bar items:

```
OverviewOrgan_NavBarHelper cNavBarHelper = new OverviewOrgan_NavBarHelper(Organization);

foreach (NavBarItem item in GetNavigationBar.Items)
{                       
    string cCaption = cNavBarHelper.UpdateNavBarItemCaption(item);
    item.Caption = cCaption;
}
```

now it is on the main thread, but I have to move it to another thread. As I know that UI should not be changed from another threat, then it is made, so I thought about using BackgroundWorker. 
     In fact, that I'm not in working with threads, can someone suggest the best solution for my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[have a look at the first answer in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker)
It explains how to use a BackgroundWorker.

But the problem will be, that the items of you navigationbar are created whithin the UI-Thread (assuming that you are using WPF) and those cannot be manipulated from another thread.

Why do you have to do it in another thread?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Invoke to update the UI from another thread.

Take a look at this post: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

For Example:

```
MethodInvoker NavBarItemInvoker = (delegate
{
   OverviewOrgan_NavBarHelper cNavBarHelper = new OverviewOrgan_NavBarHelper(Organization);

   foreach (NavBarItem item in GetNavigationBar.Items)
   {                       
       string cCaption = cNavBarHelper.UpdateNavBarItemCaption(item);
       item.Caption = cCaption;
   }
});

if (InvokeRequired)
{
   Invoke(NavBarItemInvoker);
}
else
{
    NavBarItemInvoker();
}
```

Comment: NavBarItem not have invoke method

Comment: You can let an other thread run code on the main thread. Look at the link he gave you.

Comment: The NavBarItem does not have Invoke, but the NavBar itself - which is the owner of the item. Otherwise you can find the topmost form using Application.OpenForms and call Invoke on that form. Refer to [How to get main form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000847/how-to-get-the-handle-of-the-topmost-form-in-a-winform-app)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a dispatcher for that

read more about it in this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Comment: I use Windows Forms, not WPF