# How to get the top form in a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I want to find out the top Form in my WinForms application, or the one that was displayed last (no topmost flags used), can I use this:

```
Form topForm = System.Windows.Forms.Application.
    OpenForms[System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000847/how-to-get-the-handle-of-the-topmost-form-in-a-winform-app/9269744#9269744

Comment: @LiorOhana: 'Focused' property is not set for the forms. I tried...

Comment: I think the accepted answer returns the topmost and not only the focused form.

Comment: @LiorOhana: Yeah, I saw it too. It's just too ugly for C#. I was thinking of something more elegant. The code I gave above works, I'm just not sure if it's reliable?

Comment: I don't think you can ssume the OpenForms array is ordered by the order of appearance. Do you think .NET reorder the array each time the appearance order changes? I'd be surprised if they did.