# Populated ListView being treated as empty?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ListView control which is *definitely* populated. The problem is that it's being treated as empty. When specifying an index of an item which I *know* is there, I get an "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" error.

```
public static string folderToUpdate(string folderChanged)
    {
        Main m = new Main(); // This is the class which this method is in,
                             // as a side matter I don't even know why I have to create
                             // an instance of the class I'm ACTUALLY IN
                             // (but I get a compile time error if I don't).

        string folder1 = m.lstFoldersToSync.Items[0].Text;
        string folder2 = m.lstFoldersToSync.Items[1].Text;

        string folderToUpdate;

        // If the folder changed is folder1 then the folder to update must be folder2.
        // If the folder changed is folder2 then the folder to update must be folder1.
        if (folderChanged == folder1)
        {
            folderToUpdate = folder2;
        }
        else
        {
            folderToUpdate = folder1;
        }

        return folderToUpdate;
    }
```

The error comes at line 8 where I declare and define "folder1".

**Some Clarifications: I *have* searched extensively before posting. No other question is an exact duplicate. There are many similar questions but the solution always turned out to be either an *empty* list problem or an "Off-by-one error", neither of these are the problem I'm having. Once again I stress the *Listview is populated* (on form load).**

So what can it be? Could the problem have something to do with `Main m = new Main();`?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank You.

PS: I think all the code besides lines 3, 8, and 9 are pretty much irrelevant (I may be wrong).

**EDIT: I have solved the problem by using a static field list containing the contents of the "lstFoldersToSync" control, and then accessing that (instead of trying to access the contents of the control directly).**

New working code:

```
    private static List<string> foldersToSync = new List<string>(); // This will be populated with the items in "lstFoldersToSync" control on "Main" form.

    public static string folderToUpdate(string folderChanged)
    {
       // Main m = new Main();

        string folder1 = foldersToSync[0];
        string folder2 = foldersToSync[1];

        string folderToUpdate;

        // If the folder changed is folder1 then the folder to update must be folder2.
        // If the folder changed is folder2 then the folder to update must be folder1.
        if (folderChanged == folder1)
        {
            folderToUpdate = folder2;
        }
        else
        {
            folderToUpdate = folder1;
        }

        return folderToUpdate;
    }
```

Thank you very much for all those helped me.

Comment: are you intentionally using a static function?

Comment: where is that code called from? some event? paste more code...

Comment: @attila Yes, it is static because I need to access it from another class (and I don't like instantiating, I know it's not the best).

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev It is a helper method used to determine which folder needs to be updated to match the other (but I think its irrelevant ).

Comment: @GrantWinney "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property"

Comment: it should not be static for sure and you should not be creating an instance of the form for sure

Comment: to obtain the selected folder on the form the best practice is to create a property on the form.

Answer (score 3):

yes, your problem is with the `m = new Main()` part. You need somehow to obtain a reference to your form, not create a new one.

to obtain the selected folder on the form the best practice is to create a property on the form.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Maybe provide some code? Thank you.

Comment: does the method live inside the main form? change it to be not `static` and remove the `m.` from lines 8 and 9.

Comment: That would certainly solve the problem except I need it to be static so that I can access it from another class (see my response to attila).

Comment: no, it should not be static, to access it from another class, you need to have a reference to the form. you can do something like the last response her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000847/how-to-get-the-handle-of-the-topmost-form-in-a-winform-app

Answer (score 1):

Because it's static, you'll need to pass a reference to your form/window or control to the method.

I'd consider rewriting the method so that you don't have to pass a reference to any UI elements.

```
public static string folderToUpdate(string folderChanged, List<string> foldersToSync)
{
    string folder1 = foldersToSync[0];
    string folder2 = foldersToSync[1];

    // Keep the rest the same
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then you could call it like this, sending in the list of folder names from your `ListView`:

```
yourClass.folderToUpdate("SomeFolderName",
                         lstFoldersToSync.Items.Select(i => i.Text);
```

Comment: Then "m" would be instantiated where?

Comment: But I can't write "lstFoldersToSync" from another class (which in case I didn't make clear I am doing). I get "The name 'lstFoldersToSync' does not exist in the current context" which it doesn't because "lstFoldersToSync" is in the "Main" class, and I'm calling "folderToUpdate" from _different_ class.

Comment: How can I do that ("somehow get a reference of your ListBox to that class")?

Comment: I have two classes one "Main" and one "other". In "Main" I have the "folderToUpdate" method, 
and in "other" I have a method which I want to call "folderToUpdate"

Comment: The problem is that the call to "folderToUpdate" is coming from a method in a different class which is why
I made the "folderToUpdate" method static, causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: It's hard to explain but I can't do that (I have to access it from a different class so it _must_ be static (and I can't use instantiation because that would create a _new_ one and I need to access the _orginal_ one)). I have instead solved the problem by using a static field list containing the items in "lstFoldersToSync" and then accessing that.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using a static field list containing the contents of the "lstFoldersToSync" control, and then accessing that (instead of trying to access the contents of the control directly).

New working code:

```
private static List<string> foldersToSync = new List<string>(); // This will be populated with the items in "lstFoldersToSync" control on "Main" form.

public static string folderToUpdate(string folderChanged)
{
   // Main m = new Main();

    string folder1 = foldersToSync[0];
    string folder2 = foldersToSync[1];

    string folderToUpdate;

    // If the folder changed is folder1 then the folder to update must be folder2.
    // If the folder changed is folder2 then the folder to update must be folder1.
    if (folderChanged == folder1)
    {
        folderToUpdate = folder2;
    }
    else
    {
        folderToUpdate = folder1;
    }

    return folderToUpdate;
}
```

Thank you very much for all those helped me.